# Custom options with start and end date

Tags: magento-enterprise, custom-options

I am trying to add start date and end date in admin for each custom option. I need a starting point because I don't have any idea how to proceed.

Comment: Are you referring to product's custom option?

Comment: @Adarsh: Yes, for products